# errors with subquery when fetching from different tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I ran the query below and had the error

> sub-query returns multiple rows

I have replaced all the sub query `in` with `any`, and `=` as well. Yet the problem is not solved.

```
SELECT *
from UserPost
where UserId = UserId_Param
   or UserId = any (select UserId from UserPals
                    where PalUserId = UserId_Param and FriendStatus = 1)
   or UserId = any (select PalUserId from UserPals
                    where UserId = UserId_Param and FriendStatus = 1)
and privacy = 1
and PostId not in (select PostId from UserHidePost where UserId = UserId_Param)
and Committed = 1
and Trashed = 0 

union all

select *
from UserPost
where privacy = 2
  and PostId = any(select PostId from PostCategory
                   where PalCategoryId = any (select UserPalCategoryId
                                              from PalCategory
                                              where userId = UserId_Param
                                                 or PalUserId = UserId_Param))
  and PostId not in(select PostId from UserHidePost
                    where UserId = UserId_Param)
  and Committed = 1
  and (UserId = any (select UserId from UserPals
                     where PalUserId = UserId_Param and FriendStatus = 1)
       or (select PalUserId from UserPals
           where UserId = UserId_Param and FriendStatus = 1))
  and Trashed = 0
LIMIT lim_val OFFSET lim_offset;
```

Comment: can you provide sql fiddle ?

Comment: The last sub-select has no IN/ANY. I.e executed as boolean expression, and allows only 1 row.

Answer (score 1):

The only obvious (to me) subquery that could cause this is:

```
 (select PalUserId from UserPals
       where UserId = UserId_Param and FriendStatus = 1)
```

Perhaps you want `exists`:

```
exists (select PalUserId from UserPals
        where UserId = UserId_Param and FriendStatus = 1
       )
```

As an aside, it seems a bit strange to mix `= any ()` and `in`.

Answer (score 1):

This subquery is missing an any clause:

```
SELECT *
from UserPost
where UserId = UserId_Param
   or UserId = any (select UserId from UserPals
                    where PalUserId = UserId_Param and FriendStatus = 1)
   or UserId = any (select PalUserId from UserPals
                    where UserId = UserId_Param and FriendStatus = 1)
and privacy = 1
and PostId not in (select PostId from UserHidePost where UserId = UserId_Param)
and Committed = 1
and Trashed = 0 

union all

select *
from UserPost
where privacy = 2
  and PostId = any(select PostId from PostCategory
                   where PalCategoryId = any (select UserPalCategoryId
                                              from PalCategory
                                              where userId = UserId_Param
                                                 or PalUserId = UserId_Param))
  and PostId not in(select PostId from UserHidePost
                    where UserId = UserId_Param)
  and Committed = 1
  and (UserId = any (select UserId from UserPals
                     where PalUserId = UserId_Param and FriendStatus = 1)
     ----THIS->  or (select PalUserId from UserPals
           where UserId = UserId_Param and FriendStatus = 1))-- <---
  and Trashed = 0
LIMIT lim_val OFFSET lim_offset;
```